# "Справедливости ради" — нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Но, справедливости ради, стоит сказать...**

Нужно ли "справедливости ради" брать в запятые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере **справедливости ради** — вводное слово, синонимичное выражениям **откровенно говоря**, **если быть честным**. Оно должно выделяться запятыми.

Возможно, у вас возник вопрос о необходимости первой запятой. Вводные слова отделяются от предшествующего сочинительного союза, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры (обычно это бывает при союзах **и** и **но**). Если же изъятие или перестановка вводного слова невозможны, то запятая после союза не ставится (обычно при союзе **а**).
В вашем случае перестановка вводного слова в другое место возможна (хотя для полноты картины не помешал бы более обширный контекст). Поэтому знаки препинания у вас поставлены верно.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые неверно расставлены. Обособление в данном случае не требуется: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_883